# Failed to load the package

Tags: ssis

I have two sql servers SQL1 and SQL2 and i added few packages to SQL1. Lets say SQL1 has a pacakage called P1 and it has a child package called C1.
package P1 has a connection manager called MyConn which is pointing to SQL2. 
Now the connection property of a child package set with MyConn connection manager. If I try to execute package  P1 it says following error.

**Description: Error 0xC001000A. Failed to load the package "C1" from SQL Server "SQL2". 
Make sure that the package exists on the instance of SQL Server and that you have the correct credentials to access it.**

But my packages are existing in SQL1 only. But why it is trying to connect it from SQL2 ?

Comment: We need more examples of ... everything. Are you using the SSISDB or package deployment model. How are you running P1? How does it invoke C1? What connection type is MyConn? What other error messages are there? How about warnings?

Comment: I am not using SSISDB and package deployment model. Running P1 through SQL Jobs. C1 will be invoked from P1 through Execute Package Task as external reference. MyConn is connection to SQL2. I got error while executing P1. Failed and Execute Package Task. No warnings.

Comment: I think the Connection property means to External Package Reference. That's why it is trying to load package from SQL2. Right now i have made changes as suggested by @Joe and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the child package is set to the MyConn connection manager, which is pointing to SQL2.  However, you also mentioned that both packages exist on SQL1.  You cannot use the MyConn connection for the child package since that is the wrong SQL Server.

You will need to create another SQL Connection Manager that points to SQL1 and add that to the Execute Package Task like the screenshot below (this is assuming you are using "External Reference" in the ReferenceType property, which based on your question, it sounds like you are using).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't understood External Reference initially. Now I got it. I think it will work only if i configure as you mentioned.